# How to merge cells in the same row by using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to create this kind of table in MS Excel by using Apache POI:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |first_text             |last_text                           | no_text     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10|col_11|col_12|
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX   | XX   | XX   |
 | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX   | XX   | XX   |
 | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX   | XX   | XX   |
 | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX  | XX   | XX   | XX   |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have some problems to combine the areas "first_text" and "last_text" together in the Row. The rest of the table is complete.

How can I create this kind the table overview?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress(int firstRow, int lastRow, int firstCol, int lastCol) 
sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
```

Comment: No that is not enough ! Since this Code is only for one colspan in one row sitable !!! I have already this code example